# EDI X12 tool is not able to convert the perpendicular as a segment separator

Tags: edi

While processing an EDI 210 X12 inbound file, receiving a following exception as EdiInvoice Service process failed: '', hexadecimal value 0x15, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 37.'. Because X12 Input file having a perpendicular in 106 position of ISA 16 element.

Can you please provide a solution to handle this symbol

Comment: Can you post your document?  Can you ask your partner to change it?

Comment: Also, what tool are you using to translate the 210?

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to define a `segment separator` like "|" is the *X12 ISA* segment (*ISA16*, character 106 of the *ISA* segment). Have a look at a [related tutorial](http://www.rawlinsecconsulting.com/x12tutorial/x12syn.html).
To my knowledge, characters with *ASCII* codes below `128` (hex 0x80) are allowed.

If your `EdiInvoice` service cannot handle partner-specific segment separators, you most likely have to contact the developer of your tool or the provider of your service first.

As suggested by eppye: If the sending partner can switch to an "easier" segment separator, this would also be an option, but there has to be a good reason for the partner to invest time and effort.

If the syntax of the EDI 210 X12 message conforms to the specification, the sending partner has no obligation to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

No, neither CR nor CR+LF are allowed as Segment Terminator.

X12 is based on the idea of "graphical characters", to be independent of character encodings.  CR is a non-printable character, not a graphical character.

The allowable chars in the basic char list are
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
!"&'()*+,-./:;?="

The extended character list is
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%@[]_{}\|<>~^`#$"

Supporting the extended characters is a Trading Partner agreement item.

To be "X12 legal", a character from the basic set must be used.  If the extended set is supported, a char from it may be used.

"X12 legal" is only as important as your trading partner thinks it is (or their software).

Using CR or CR+LF is not uncommon, even if frowned upon by purists.

Having a CR or CR+LF after each Segment Terminator is more common.

Answer (score 0):

some companies indeed use non-printable character as segment terminator. AFAIK this is OK in ANSI X12. Sort of smart, as you are not allowed to use the segment terminator in your data, and data will (almost;-)) never contain hex 15. I have seen hex 07, carriage return etc.
.
possible solutions:
1. Contact the provider of the service, they should fix it.
2. Ask edi-partner if they can use other segment terminator.
3. pre-process the file and replace that character. Maybe not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which EDI tool you're using, but another option is to define the element and segment terminators in your partner profile in your tool. I've done this in Sterling Integrator and know others support this as well.

Answer (score 0):

> ### In your case you need to confirm the trading partner of the below rule so that they may not get mistaken ISA16 with Segment Terminator or Suffix .

**ISA16 (Sub Element separator)**

- Char
- 3a if the type is Hex

> Limited to the values in the ASCII character set.

**Segment terminator**

- ~ if the type is Char
- 7e if the type is Hex.
- empty

> but if you do, you need to designate a suffix.This element is limited to the values in the ASCII character set.

**Suffix**

- either None
- CR (carriage return)
- LF(line feed)
- CRLF (carriage return/line feed).

**Various combination for Segment Terminator  and Suffix**

- Segment terminator
- Segment terminator + carriage return
- Segment terminator + line feed
- Segment terminator + carriage return/line feed
- Carriage return
- Line feed
- Carriage return/line feed